# Model relationships in DAO pattern

Tags: java, model, persistence, dao

I'm implementing a web application and I need to connect to a DB. The idea is using a DAO pattern but I have a doubt. Imagine that I have the next tables:

- Department: Businnes departments.
- Employee: Employees of my businnes.
- DepartmentEmployee: A table to know in which department works each employee.

This will generate two models, Departments and Employees. My question is, Would Employee model store a Department variable? Would Department have a list of employees in its model?

Comment: For a richly populated object yes, for a DTO, probably just IDs or some lighter weight object. This is the kind of problem than an ORM sorts out for you without having to think about it too much, YMMV.

Comment: And I would not consider it as "two models" but rather "two entities in a model"

Comment: I'll use hibernate but I don't understand yet how to keep track of all relationship between them. What happens if I need to get all employees of a given department? What I need in the models? Or is all managed in DAO implementations?

Comment: Unless an employee can be a member of multiple departments it might make more sense to get rid of the DepartmentEmployee table and have the department id as a foreign key on the employee table.

Comment: That is the case. A department has many employees and an employee can work in different departments (yes, this is not the best example but I'm sort of ideas :P)

Comment: I am building something similar, what I decided to do is keep a Dao for each corresponding entity, (not a value object), there you can keep all your database logic and  it can populate the entity and create objects, its with PHP though